# How to clone a repo in Windows which contains an invalid symbol for windows file system

Tags: git

I want to clone a git repo, however there are folder in this repo named like "Image:Arrow". The ":" mark is an invalid symbol for the file name and folder name in Windows, so I am not able to clone it at a windows system. Even I download the repo as zip file, this zip file is not able to unzip it.

How could I be able to clone this repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated by this [PR (Pull Request)](https://github.com/mozilla/dxr/pull/301) (for another repo), that folder would need to be renamed (if cloning it on Windows is important)

Unless the maintainer of the repo rename the folder "Image:Arrow", the repo won't be clonable on Windows.