# fatal: cannot create directory at ' ': No such file or directory

Tags: windows, git, centos

I  clone project from server centOS to window , here is the error I got:

```
 git clone ssh://git@xx.xxx.xx.xx:/home/git/srv/repos/projet.t2.company.com.git PROJ_V2
Cloning into 'PROJ_V2'...
git@xx.xxx.xx.xx's password:
remote: Counting objects: 7078, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5672/5672), done.
remote: Total 7078 (delta 1276), reused 6862 (delta 1073)
Receiving objects: 100% (7078/7078), 107.96 MiB | 18.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1276/1276), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
fatal: cannot create directory at ' ': No such file or directory
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: What does `git status` output? That looks vaguely like a directory with an invalid path (on Windows) was checked in.

Comment: I clone to c:/wamp/www

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233483/how-to-clone-a-repo-in-windows-which-contains-an-invalid-symbol-for-windows-file

Comment: Where you are cloning to is not likely relevant (or git would have already complained I think). And that's not what I asked. Can you show us the output from `git status`?